# Crystal Report with multiple row within single row

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

I am using visual studio 2010. I want to create a crystal report with multiple rows within one row like this:

```
     ______________________
    |   |   |   |__________|
    | 1 |   |   |__________|
    |___|___|___|__________|
```

Comment: Instead of splitting one row to multiple rows, try merging several rows to one for each of the other cells. Look for a row-span feature.

Comment: can you provide sample data on how report should look like so that we can see the feasibility of implmenting in Crystal Reports

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Cross Tab](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/493334/Custom-sorting-for-Crystal-Report-Cross-Tab) to achieve your requirements.